# Как построить таблицу в HTML без использования CSS

Tags: html

[image: таблица]
Нужно создать таблицу как на картинке без применения CSS

Answer (score 10):

Примерно так:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Заголовок1</td>
      <td>Заголовок2</td>
      <td>Список2</td>
      <td>Заголовок3</td>
      <td>Картинка2</td>
      <td>Список2</td>
      <td>Заголовок3</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Текст2</td>
      <td>Текст1</td>
      <td>Картинка3</td>
      <td>Текс3</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Текст4</td>
      <td>и</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Список1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Текст5</td>
      <td>Список3</td>
      <td>Картинка1</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
      <td>_ _ _ _ _</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Или еще так:

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Заголовок1</td>
      <td>Заголовок2</td>
      <td>Список2</td>
      <td>Заголовок3</td>
      <td>Картинка2</td>
      <td>Список2</td>
      <td>Заголовок3</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr >
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>Текст2</td>
      <td>Текст1</td>
      <td>Картинка3</td>
      <td>Текс3</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Текст4</td>
      <td>и</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Список1</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td>Текст5</td>
      <td>Список3</td>
      <td>Картинка1</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
      <td>- - - - - - - </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Или воспользоваться генератором: http://www.apsolyamov.ru/files/html-table-generator.html

p.s. на самом деле на просторах интернета генераторов очень много.